# Symmetry property of the Cayley transform on Stiefel manifolds

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, determinant, kronecker-product, stiefel-manifolds

### Context

I am interested in the Cayley transform on the Stiefel manifold $\mathcal V_{np}$ at the point $I_{np} = (I_p, 0_{p,n-p})^\top$. For a matrix $X$ of the form
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix}
A & -B^\top\\
B & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $A\in \mathbb R^{p\times p}$ such that $A^\top = -A$ and $B\in \mathbb R^{p\times(n-p)}$, the Cayley transform $C: \mathbb R^{n\times n}\to \mathcal V_{np}$ is defined by
$$
C(X) = (I - X/2)^{-1}(1 + X/2) I_{np}
$$
In practice, $X$ is parameterized linearly by a vector $\varphi$ with dimension $d_\mathcal V=p(p-1)/2 + p(n-p)$, and we are actually interested in the map $\bar C(\varphi) = C(X_\varphi)$.

### My question

In order to make changes of variable relying on $\bar C$, a recent paper [1] uses the generalized Jacobian determinant:
$$
J(\varphi) = | d_\varphi \bar C^* d_\varphi \bar C | \,.
$$
**I would like to prove** that $J(-\varphi) = J(\varphi)$. I can easily verify this property numerically by approximating the Jacobian with finite differences. It is also relatively intuitive if we think of the Stiefel manifold as a generalization of the sphere.

### What I have so far

The paper mentioned above [1] also showed in particular that
$$
J(\varphi) = |\Gamma_\mathcal V^\top \left[\left[ (I_n - X_\varphi)^{-1} I_{np}I_{np}^\top (I_n - X_\varphi)^{-\top} \right] \otimes \left[ (I_n - X_\varphi)^{-\top} (I_n - X_\varphi)^{-1} \right]\right]\Gamma_\mathcal V|
$$
(with $\Gamma_\mathcal V$ denoting the linear map $\varphi \mapsto X_\varphi$ ; it is thus a rectangular $n^2 \times d_\mathcal V$ matrix).

Using the property of the Kronecker product, this gives in particular
$$
J(\varphi) = |\Gamma_\mathcal V^\top \left[ (I_n - X_\varphi)^{-1} \otimes (I_n - X_\varphi)^{-\top}\right] \left[ I_{np}I_{np}^\top \otimes I_n\right] \left[ (I_n - X_\varphi)^{-\top} \otimes  (I_n - X_\varphi)^{-1} \right]\Gamma_\mathcal V|\,.
$$
Using the fact that $X_\varphi$ is skew-symmetric, and using [commutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix), I can show that
$$
J(-\varphi) = |\Gamma_\mathcal V^\top \left[ (I_n - X_\varphi)^{-1} \otimes (I_n - X_\varphi)^{-\top}\right] \left[ I_n \otimes I_{np}I_{np}^\top \right] \left[ (I_n - X_\varphi)^{-\top} \otimes  (I_n - X_\varphi)^{-1} \right]\Gamma_\mathcal V|\,,
$$
i.e. only the Kronecker product in the middle differs between the matrices in $J(\varphi)$ and $J(-\varphi)$. Numerically, the two formulas above match even when replacing $X_\varphi$ by a random skew-symmetric matrix, which leads me to hope that relatively simple linear algebra may allow to conclude.

Any help would be appreciated!

[1] Jauch, M., Hoff, P. D., & Dunson, D. B. (2020). Random orthogonal matrices and the Cayley transform. Bernoulli, 26(2), 1560–1586. https://doi.org/10.3150/19-BEJ1176

Answer (score 1):

Differential writes
\begin{eqnarray}
d\mathbf{C} 
&=& 
+\frac12 \left( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X}/2 \right)^{-1}
(d\mathbf{X}) 
\left(\mathbf{C}+ \mathbf{I}_{np} \right) \\
&=&
\left( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X}/2 \right)^{-1}
(d\mathbf{X}) 
\left( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X}/2 \right)^{-1}
\mathbf{I}_{np}
\end{eqnarray}
since
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{C}(\mathbf{X})+\mathbf{I}_{np} 
&=& 
\left( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X}/2 \right)^{-1}
\left \lbrace
\left( \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X}/2 \right) +
\left( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X}/2 \right)
\right \rbrace
\mathbf{I}_{np} \\
&=&
2
\left( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X}/2 \right)^{-1}
\mathbf{I}_{np}
\end{eqnarray*}

From here use the vec trick
\begin{eqnarray}
d\mathbf{c} 
&=& 
\left \lbrace
\mathbf{I}_{np}^T
\left( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X}/2 \right)^{-T}
\otimes 
\left( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X}/2 \right)^{-1}
\right \rbrace
d\mathbf{x}
\end{eqnarray}
The Jacobian writes
$\mathbf{J}=\mathbf{U}\otimes \mathbf{V}$
where $\mathbf{U}=\mathbf{I}_{np}^T
\left( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X}/2 \right)^{-T}$
and
$\mathbf{V}=\left( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X}/2 \right)^{-1}$.

Looking at the Jacobian determinant,
we must compute the determinant of the matrix
$$
\mathbf{J}^T \otimes \mathbf{J}
=
(\mathbf{U}\otimes \mathbf{V})^T
(\mathbf{U}\otimes \mathbf{V})
=
\mathbf{U}^T \mathbf{U} \otimes \mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{V}
$$

It is easy to see that
$\mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{V}$ evaluated for $-\varphi$
is equal to $\mathbf{V}^T \mathbf{V}$ evaluated for $\varphi$. and similar for $\mathbf{U}^T \mathbf{U}$.
This shows that the Jacobian determinant
is unchanged if $\varphi \rightarrow \varphi$.

To do that, we can use the fact that $\mathbf{X}^T=-\mathbf{X}$
so that
$\mathbf{V}(-\varphi)
= 
\left[ \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X}(-\varphi)/2 \right]^{-1}
=
\left( \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{X}(\varphi)/2 \right]^{-1}
=
\left[ \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X}(\varphi)/2 \right]^{-T}
=
\mathbf{V}^T
$.

Comment: Hi, shouldn't there be an additional Kronecker product in the last line? Something like $\left\{(I_{np}^\top \otimes I) \times \left[ (I + \mathbf{X}/2)^{-1} \otimes (I - \mathbf{X}/2)^{-1} \right] \right\}$? Does the invariance still hold in this case?

Comment: I suspect that the equality only holds at the level of the determinant $J(\varphi)$.

Comment: You were right. I was unprecise in my previous demonstration. See the update from the vectorization trick.

Comment: I agree with your update formula for $\mathbf{J}^\top \otimes \mathbf{J}$. However I think that $\mathbf{U}^\top \mathbf{U}$ is not invariant when changing $\varphi \to - \varphi$: I get $\mathbf{U}^\top \mathbf{U} = (I + \mathbf{X}/2)^{-1} I_{np} I_{np}^\top (I - \mathbf{X}/2)^{-1}$, which is not necessarily the same when we change $\varphi$ to $-\varphi$.

Comment: Also note that $\mathbf{U}^\top \mathbf{U}$ does not have full rank and thus has determinant zero ; it is only when we multiply $\mathbf{J}^\top\otimes \mathbf{J}$ by the linear change coordinates $\Gamma_{\mathcal{V}}: \varphi \mapsto \mathbf{x}$ that we obtain a non-zero determinant.

Comment: You are right, I have been too expeditive in my answer. Did you find a way to demonstrate the result you want ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am starting to suspect that the property might actually be false. In my first numerical experiments I had only checked the property for (relatively) small values of $X$. Now I am trying with larger values for $X$ (random coefficients with variance 1000-10000), and the precision in the equality $J(\varphi) = J(-\varphi)$ decreases as $X$ goes to infinity. However I can't figure out if this is due to a loss of precision or to the equality failing (in which case it would just be a very good approximation for relatively small values of $X$).